# Why can't I post a new question even though I haven't posted one 90 minutes ago?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

Why can't I post my question? An error message shows as seen in the screenshot when I try to post it:

[image]

Comment: @Mat, I think length and number of codes are normal

Comment: and I didn't ask 90 min ago

Comment: Are you visiting the site from a public place like a library or university campus?

Comment: Yes, I am at university !

Comment: Then someone else with the same IP recently asked a question. I'm not sure if you can somehow work around this restriction...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent one user to use multiple accounts and ask tons of (poor) questions a day, there is a threshold on IP basis for users with a history of low-quality posts.

Probably some other student has asked some questions, and now you have hit the threshold. You can come back in a few minutes and ask again.

Please read [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/245360).

Comment: now makes sense. thanks man.

Comment: @sin: See the link I included. It explains all the rate limiting rules in place.